# Android: Call onActivityResult() from dialog fragment

Tags: android

When I was using a dialog fragment inside a activity then onActivityResult() is calling correctly but now i have changed activity to fragment due to my requirement . In that case images are not loading to imageview from camera and gallery.....

Code i was using to call in dialog fragment is...

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Code used in fragment ........

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{                                                                                // Load the images from gallery and camera
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.icon);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }
    else if (requestCode == TAKE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        pic = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        icon.setImageBitmap(pic);

    }
}
```

Code used for fragment transaction is ....

```
 MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
            myDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "DialogFragment");
```

Over all code of dialog fragment.........

```
 public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MY_DIALOG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog d = getDialog();

        if (d!=null){
            int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            d.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

        ImageButton FAB=(ImageButton)root.findViewById(R.id.imagesave);
        FAB.setOnClickListener(this);

        LinearLayout linearbutton=(LinearLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.linearbutton);

        LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.linear);
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

        ImageButton text=(ImageButton)root.findViewById(R.id.imageText);
        text.setOnClickListener(this);

        ImageButton pencil=(ImageButton)root.findViewById(R.id.imagePencil);
        pencil.setOnClickListener(this);

        ImageButton gallery=(ImageButton)root.findViewById(R.id.imageGallery);
        gallery.setOnClickListener(this);

        ImageButton camera=(ImageButton)root.findViewById(R.id.imageCamera);
        camera.setOnClickListener(this);

        return root;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imagesave: {
                getDialog().dismiss();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setTitle("Saving");
                pDialog.setMessage("please wait..............");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();

                FAB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        FAB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, 2000);


                radioGroup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                imagesize.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                clear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.relative);
                content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();

                File myDir = new File("/sdcard/MyCollection");
                myDir.mkdirs();
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
                File file = new File(myDir, fname);
                if (file.exists()) file.delete();
                FileOutputStream outStream;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                i = 0;
                break;
            }
            case R.id.linear: {
                getDialog().dismiss();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.imageText:
            {
                editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                imagesize.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                radioGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                clear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You have selected text ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getDialog().dismiss();
                break;
            }

            case R.id.imagePencil: {
                getDialog().dismiss();

                clear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imagesize.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                radioGroup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You have selected pencil ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                i=0;
                break;
            }

            case R.id.imageGallery: {
                getDialog().dismiss();
                clear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                radioGroup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                imagesize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                final Fragment callingFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById();
                Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                callingFragment.startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);



                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You have selected gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;
            }

            case R.id.imageCamera: {
                getDialog().dismiss();
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                clear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                radioGroup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                imagesize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), TAKE_REQUEST);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You have selected camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the activity from your fragment. Change your call to:

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
yourFragment.startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

UPDATE:

In your dialog fragment write something like this:

```
final Fragment callingFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById();
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
callingFragment.startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Depending on your setup you may need to `getSupportFragmentManager()` and/or method `findFragmentByTag()`. It depends on how and where you added your fragment.

UPDATE 2:

```
final Fragment homeFragment = (HomeFragment)getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.containerView);
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
homeFragment.startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Comment: Sir it is showing error Non-static method 'startActivityForResult'

Comment: Where do want to start the intent? On the fragment itself? Please post the code.

Comment: I want to start intent in the dialog fragment

Comment: Showing error that findFragmentById (String) in FragmentManager cannot  be applied

Comment: This methods requires an int, not a string.

Comment: sory i am new in android so what should be the value of int

Comment: Please add your code where you add your fragment with fragment transaction. Either you add it using an id or a name/tag.

Comment: This is not what I meant. Somewhere in your code you should have something like this: `fragmentTransaction.add(yourFragment, "fragmentName")` or `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentId, yourFragment);` Or do you inflate by XML?

Comment: Fragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,homeFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: still showing the error that inconvertible type  cannot cast

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91831/discussion-between-thomas-r-and-dev-kumar).

Answer (score 2):

If the parent activity is also overriding `onActivityResult` then all calls to `startActivityForResult` will return to the parent activity. Now, to pass that call down to all fragments in the activity is by calling the base class' implementation.

In other words, if your activity (and its fragments) need `onActivityResult` all you need to do is call the base activity `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    //this makes sure the child fragments receive this event
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onActivityResult` will get called in parent activity of your fragment.
you need to pass this event to your fragment.

you can use interface as callback here to pass on this event.

Answer (score 1):

use this code its working for me

```
case R.id.take_pic:
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE),
                TAKE_REQUEST);
        break;
    case R.id.browse_pic:

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_REQUEST);
        break;
```

and here is onActivityresult

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == TAKE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        pic = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(pic);

    }
    if (requestCode == SELECT_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            InputStream stream = getActivity().getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(data.getData());
            pic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            stream.close();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(pic);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```