# Decode file to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, decode

I have an activity that takes a picture saved in the SD and after the snapshot. I managed to take a picture and save it but then that saved him turn it into a bitmap file.

This is my class:

```
public class CamaraFicha extends Activity {

    private Button bt_hacerfoto;  
    private ImageView img; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camara_ficha);

         img = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

         String rutaFoto = "/mnt/extSdCard/UGREP/";
         File ruta_sd = new File(rutaFoto);
         File f = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath(), "foto1.jpg");
         Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(f);
         Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
         cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
         startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
    }


       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  

             if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
                String rutaFoto = "/mnt/extSdCard/UGREP/";
                File ruta_sd = new File(rutaFoto);
                File f = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath(), "foto1.jpg");
                Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f);
                img.setImageBitmap(bMap);        
             } 
       }
}
```

Can someone help me decode the file to turn it into a bitmap in the method `protected void onActivityResult`

Tranks for your help!!

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: @Simas this line:  Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f); it says that the type of f should be a string

Comment: this is the solution: `Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.toString()); ` add  `f.toString()`

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33032214/android-call-onactivityresult-from-dialog-fragment/33035970#33035970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` needs the path to the file as a `String`, not as a `File`. So in your case, you need to do:

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Or just use a string with the path to your file directly, instead of creating a `File` first.

Answer (score 2):

`BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` expects a `String` path. You can get it from your file like so:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
```